# ADFS 2.0 - No Home Realm Discovery

Tags: asp.net, adfs, ws-federation

I have the following network configuration for federating an asp.net application, but I am not seeing my home realm discovery screen. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

ADFS #1
  - Relying Party Trust with ADFS #2

ADFS #2
  - Relying Party Trust with my web application.
  - Claims Provider Trust with ADFS #1
  - Claims Provider Trust with Active Directory

Webserver
  - ASP.NET application with an STS reference to ADFS #2.

I thought that when I tried to access the website, I would be shown the canned home realm discovery screen where I could choose the realm for ADFS #1 or #2. Instead I am always prompted for credentials to the domain of ADFS #2 (to which my application has an STS reference). Any help would be appreciated. I thought this configuration was correct.

Comment: Have you seen the realm selection before? Usually if you pick one realm from the drop down it auto authenticates you for 30 days. You must clear your cookies in order to see the realm discover page.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I deleted my cookies and home realm discovery was shown again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the realm selection before? Usually if you pick one realm from the drop down it auto authenticates you for 30 days. You must clear your cookies in order to see the realm discover page. –

Comment: Or alternatively set a flag in the web.config to never remember the selection.